# QT how to connect via seperate method

Tags: qt

I have a small serial port class and want to connect the readData signal from outside

serial.cpp

```
void SerialPort::connectToHandler(const QObject* receiver, QMetaMethod* method) {
    connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, receiver, method);
}
```

Would the two function parameters be correct as they are?

This method should be connected

```
void MyClass::handleDisplayEvents() {
}
```

So I try to combine both

```
void MyClass::initialize() {
    port->connectToHandler(this, &MyClass::handleDisplayEvents);
}
```

But I get an error like "argument of type void MyClass::*() is incompatible with typ QMetaMethod"

Can this be done at all and if so what would I have to adapt - sorry I am at the beginning with c++ and QT

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't use the `connect` overload that takes a `QMetaMethod`, but the ones taking `PointerToMemberFunction` (like in your example) or `Functor` which are just template types of the Qt methods.

Probably the cleanest solution would be to template your `connectToHandler` in a similar manner (Keep in mind to move the implementation to the header file):

```
template<typename PointerToMemberFunction>
void SerialPort::connectToHandler(const QObject* receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method) {
    connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, receiver, method);
}
```

You *could* restrict the template type but `connect` already fails to compile with the wrong type anyway which should be fine for a simple method like this.

## Alternatively

You could also just define your own signal in `SerialPort` which just forwards the `QSerialPort::readyRead` signal and connect to that from outside:

serial.h

```
class SerialPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Signal()
    {
        connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, SerialPort:readyRead);
        // [...]
    }
    // [...]

signals:
    void readyRead();
    // [...]
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
void MyClass::initialize() {
    connect(port, &SerialPort::readyRead, this, &MyClass::handleDisplayEvents);
}
```